# Google Sheets Script to Extend Conditional Formatting to new last row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

About once a week, I import data into a spreadsheet from a .csv file and do append data to current sheet and it adds new rows to the sheet each week. Now I have 3 different Conditional Format's set up that Highlights things under different circumstances. This requires me to edit each conditional format and extend it to the now NEW last row number. So I'm looking for a script that can add a menu button to do this mundane task for me.

And I can't just have more rows prior to the import, because I have an ArrayFormula in one of the columns and this causes the "append to current sheet" import to still add new rows at the bottom.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script docs list a "copy" function for Conditional Format Rules, wouldn't that do the trick?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule